# nginx set up phpmyadmin alias

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin

I installed Nginx, php7 fpm, and phpmyadmin using `brew`.

I can not set up an alias for phpmyadmin. I want something like `localhost/phpmyadmin`

My config file:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
  index index.php index.htm;
  alias /usr/local/Cellar/phpmyadmin/4.6.1/share/phpmyadmin;
}
```

I'm getting `403 Forbidden` error when I try to access the url

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578102/working-with-alias-inside-location/37579111#37579111). And you should be using [root](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and not [alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)

Comment: is root better? @RichardSmith

Comment: Yes, check the links.  The alias documentation says that root is better.

Comment: I don't want to put inside /www it will be in another dir

Comment: The equivalent root statement is: `root /usr/local/Cellar/phpmyadmin/4.6.1/share`

Comment: yes but it says when you use /www not another separate folder