# Is it possible to have web index outside public html?

Tags: php, http, nginx

Say a website has this folder structure

```
/index.php
/<public>
   dikpic.jpeg
```

And when someone visits the website I want the physical web root to point to `/public`,
like `mywebsite.com/dikpic.jpeg`

(without url rewrites).

This can be achieved with the `root /myuser/public;` command.

But I also want to load the index.php file from outside this directory:

```
index /myuser/index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm-myuser.sock;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

The problem is with the location try files block that assumes `/` is the web root :(

Any way around this?

---

I should also point out that the index.php is the only script on the website.
So I don't really care if any other requests for .php files are ignored. The index.php handles url rewriting stuff...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i want to access index.php in folder outside root (nginx windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60246101/i-want-to-access-index-php-in-folder-outside-root-nginx-windows)

Comment: not really, sorry...

Comment: Why would your index.php need to be outside your public dir? Your public dir is your web root, if your index.php is the php version of index.html, then the public dir is the only obvious place for it to live.

Comment: because the server hosts multiple websites that have the same index, and I was thinking to have a single file, instead of copying to every website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an additional `location` block for that, although it doesn't seems an elegant solution to me:

```
location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm-myuser.sock;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
}

location = /index.php {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm-myuser.sock;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    /full/path/to/your/index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        /index.php;
}
```

Exact matching locations have a priority over regex matching ones, so the first block will be used for any PHP file request except the `/index.php`. You don't even need to define a root for the second location, setting right `SCRIPT_FILENAME` FastCGI parameter value will be enough.

**Update**

I didn't notice the very last sentence of your question, but if you didn't care for any other PHP files, only the second block `location = /index.php { ... }` will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can create symlinks of your index.php [here is how to do that.](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-linux-using-the-ln-command/)

And as result you will have single index.php to all your websites